# Erro ao recolher valor de tipagem dinâmica

Tags: c, tipagem

Estou com problemas para fazer o recolhimento dos valores em uma tipagem dinâmica em C.

Os valores inseridos como `char`, `const char *`, `int`, `void *` e `long int` funcionam perfeitamente quando colocados no `printf` (imprime o valor sem passar o campo da `union`), mas quando uso os dados do tipo `float` e `double` o valor retornado é sempre `0`, só funciona se passar o caminho completo da variável da `union`.

**var.c:**

```
#include <var.h>

const char *__var_type_2_string(var v){
    switch (v.type){
        case CHAR:
            return "Char";
        case INTEGER:
            return "Int";
        case L_INTEGER:
            return "Long Int";
        case FLOAT:
            return "Float";
        case DOUBLE:
            return "Double";
        case STRING:
            return "String";
        case POINTER:
            return "Pointer";
    }

    return "Undefined";
}
```

**var.h:**

```
#ifndef  __VAR_H__
#define  __VAR_H__

#define typeof(var) _Generic( (var),\
char: CHAR,\
int: INTEGER,\
long int: L_INTEGER,\
char *: STRING,\
const char *: STRING,\
void *: POINTER,\
float: FLOAT,\
double: DOUBLE,\
default: 0)

#define set_wtype(var, out) _Generic( (var),\
char: (out.data.c = var),\
int: (out.data.i = var),\
long int: (out.data.l = var),\
char *: (out.data.s = var),\
const char *: (out.data.s = var),\
void *: (out.data.p = var),\
default: 0)

#define set_wtypef(var, out) _Generic( (var),\
float: (out.data.f = var),\
double: (out.data.d = var),\
default: 0)

enum VAR_TYPE{
    CHAR        = 1,
    INTEGER     = 2,
    L_INTEGER   = 3,
    FLOAT       = 4,
    DOUBLE      = 5,
    STRING      = 6,
    POINTER     = 7
};

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) _var{
    union _data{
        char c;
        int i;
        long int l;
        float f;
        double d;
        const char *s;
        void *p;
    } data;
    enum VAR_TYPE type;
}var;

const char *__var_type_2_string(var v);

#define var_set(var, dta)\
    var.type = typeof(dta);\
    set_wtype(dta, var)
#define var_setf(var, dta)\
    var.type = typeof(dta);\
    set_wtypef(dta, var)
//#define var_get(var) var.data
#define var_type(var) var.type
#define var_typeS(var) __var_type_2_string(var)

#endif  /*VAR_H*/
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <var.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv){
    /*Array*/

    var vec[5];
    var_set(vec[0], 37);
    var_set(vec[1], 6625L);
    var_set(vec[2], "Text");
    var_set(vec[3], (char)'A');
    var_setf(vec[4], 13.33f);

    for(int x=0; x<5; x++){
        puts(var_typeS(vec[x]));
    }

    puts("\nResultados: ");
    printf("vec[0]= %i\n", vec[0]);
    printf("vec[1]= %li\n", vec[1]);
    printf("vec[2]= %s\n", vec[2]);
    printf("vec[3]= %c\n", vec[3]);
    printf("vec[4]= %f\n", vec[4]);
    printf("vec[4]= %f\n", vec[4].data.f);

    return 0;
}
```

Existe algum jeito de estar imprimindo o valor do `vec[4]` sem passar `vec[4].data.f` no `printf`?

**saida:**

```
Int
Long Int
String
Char
Float

Resultados: 
vec[0]= 37
vec[1]= 6625
vec[2]= Text
vec[3]= A
vec[4]= 0.000000
vec[4]= 13.330000
```

`compilado em gcc-v6.3`

Answer (score 1):

Chamar a `printf` dessa forma, passando diretamente a `struct var` como argumento (`vec[0]`, `vec[1]`, etc) não é uma boa prática porque pode levar à [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Inclusive, compilando-se o código como ele está atualmente com a *flag* `-Wall` é possível observar uma série de *warnings*.

Assim, eu diria que uma solução mais apropriada é criar uma função `__var_value_2_string()`, similar à `__var_type_2_string`, porém para realizar a conversão de todos os **valores** (ao invés dos **tipos**) para `char *`.

Uma possível implementação dessa função é a seguinte:

```
void __var_value_2_string(var v, char **out)
{
    char *s = NULL;
    char *default_str = "undefined";

    switch (v.type) {
        case CHAR:
            s = malloc(2 * sizeof(char));
            s[0] = v.data.c;
            s[1] = '\0';
            break;
        case INTEGER:
            s = malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(s, 21, "%i", v.data.i);
            break;
        case L_INTEGER:
            s = malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(s, 21, "%li", v.data.l);
            break;
        case FLOAT:
            s = malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(s, 21, "%f", v.data.f);
            break;
        case DOUBLE:
            s = malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(s, 21, "%lf", v.data.d);
            break;
        case STRING:
            s = malloc((strlen(v.data.s) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(s, v.data.s);
            break;
        case POINTER:
            s = malloc(19 * sizeof(char));
            snprintf(s, 19, "0x%p", v.data.p);
            break;
        default:
            s = malloc((strlen(default_str) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(s, default_str);
    }

    (*out) = s;
}
```

Então, poderia-se adicionar em `var.h` um novo `typedef`:

```
#define var_valueS(var, out) __var_value_2_string(var, out)
```

E, finalmente, na `main()`, os resultados poderiam ser exibidos fazendo-se:

```
char *buffers[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    var_valueS(vec[i], &buffers[i]);

puts("\nResultados: ");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    printf("vec[%d] = %s\n", i, buffers[i]);
```

Para concluir, é importante perceber que os *buffers* estão sendo alocados via `malloc()` e que, eventualmente, a memória associada a esses *buffers* deve ser liberada através da função `free()`.

Comment: Eu pensei em fazer desse jeito, mas eu queria algo mais dinâmico, por isso o enum esta na primeira posição, para quando for passar a variável para o printf, já ter o valor registrado logo nos primeiros bytes da `struct`. O que eu realmente precisava é de uma solução para o `printf` lançar os valores `float`.